# In what circumstances can the C# 'is' keyword throw an exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I stumbled upon something like the following in our code base...

```
    protected bool IsThing(object item)
    {
        try
        {
            return item is Thing;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to work out if there is any circumstance in which this `catch` will ever be visited?

Comment: The catch is useless. Exception should bubble up with a throw or logged.

Comment: @JonSkeet can make the is operator throw an exception http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Comment: @DamienJoe, the problem isn't what the exception returns, the problem is that it can never get hit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `is` keyword never throws an exception.
That is a useless method and you should remove it.

`if(IsThing(item)) {...}` could and *should* be replaced with `if(item is Thing) { ... }`

Comment: I think the sentiment of the original wording was perfectly valid ;)

Comment: @gingerbreadboy Haha, I think whoever wrote the method was trying to [ensure a job for life](https://www.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html)

Comment: Is there any documentation anywhere which explicitly states that 'is' will never throw an exception?

Comment: @gingerbreadboy: [Elsewhere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx), it says, "You can use [the **is** and **as**] operators to test whether a cast will succeed without causing an exception to be thrown."

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of the 'is' keyword is that an exception will not occur!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx

Comment: Yeah I looked at this msdn entry but it didn't explicitly state that no exception could be throw by `is` so I came here with my question. Thanks though :)